# FusedLocationProviderClient api exception while requisition for location updates coordinates

Tags: android, android-gps, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

I am requesting location updates from the FusedLocationApi after granting run time permissions. So when checking for location setting in

```
mSettingsClient?.checkLocationSettings(mLocationSettingsRequest)
```

it always fails and goes to

```
mSettingsClient?.addOnFailureListener(mLocationSettingsRequest)
```

and gives

> com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:

which is status code for DEVELOPER_ERROR but this happening only on vivo 1609(6.0, funtouch OS_3.0 ) phone and working on all other phones(able to log the coordinates).
I am not able to find any reason behind this why DEVELOPER_ERROR comes on that phone

Comment: Are you using google login and Firbase in your app.

Comment: no google login and firebase just used location, maps & google service dependancies

Comment: I am also getting the same issue.